# Program not computing subtraction properly

Tags: c++, subtraction

I'm working on a math assignment, not anything that requires programming, but since I enjoy it I try to do it for some of the assignments just to see if I can. This one was writing an integer as a sum of Fibonacci numbers. Here's the code for it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> fib;
  vector<int> sum;
  int n = 0;
  int total = 0;

  cout << "Enter a number." << endl;
  cin >> n;
  total = n;

  fib.push_back(1);
  fib.push_back(1);

  for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
  {
    fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
  }

  for(int i = n; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    if(total - fib[i] >= 0)
    {
      sum.push_back(fib[i]);
      total -= fib[i];
    }
    if(total == 0)
    {
      break;
    }
    if(total < 0)
    {
      cout << "Program Error. Exiting" << endl;
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  cout << "The sequence of the fewest Fibonacci numbers adding to " << n << " is:" << endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < sum.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << sum[i] << endl;
  }

  return(0);
}
```

It seems to run fine until I try to put in the number 7.

When it gets to `if(total - fib[i] >= 0)` it works as its supposed to. `total` is supposed to get down to 2 and `fib[i]` also reaches 2 for some `i`. It calculates this fine and goes into the if statement. but then when it does `total -= fib[i]` it makes `total = -1`, thus breaking the code.

Any suggestions as how to fix this?

Edit: It's not just 7. I tried 100, and got extremely large (both positive and negative) numbers that I was too lazy to see if they actually added up to 100 since there were about 30 or so of them. I'm not sure where this would come from.

Edit2: The issue with the #100 is not that it doesn't work, but the value is too large for an int to hold, for anyone having similar situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
}
```

To

```
for (int i = 2; i <=n; i++) {
    int tmp = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
    fib.push_back(tmp);
}
```

`vector<int> fib` allocates 8 elements space by default, vector[8+] access will cause memory error, you should use push_back(), vector will auto reallocate space when it's full.

Comment: Awesome. thanks for the code snippet, and the explanation. That makes sense.

Comment: `Vector allocates 8 elements space by default` False! It allocates how much you tell it (via constructor, push_back etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Before your line `for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)` the size of your `fib` vector is only 2, because you didn't reserve any space for it, and you called `push_back` only twice.

This means, if you try to set any element of it after that, you will encounter **undefined behavior**. You accessed memory which doesn't belong to you.

Comment: Right, I hand't seen that. Thanks for the helpful feedback!